# Printing the free monad

Tags: haskell, monads, traversal, free-monad

One can translate a free monad to any other monad, but given a value of type `Free f x`, I want to print the whole tree, not map every node of the AST generated to some other node in another monad.

Gabriel Gonzales [uses](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html) the value directly

```
showProgram :: (Show a, Show r) => Free (Toy a) r -> String
showProgram (Free (Output a x)) =
    "output " ++ show a ++ "\n" ++ showProgram x
showProgram (Free (Bell x)) =
    "bell\n" ++ showProgram x
showProgram (Free Done) =
    "done\n"
showProgram (Pure r) =
    "return " ++ show r ++ "\n"
```

which can be abstracted away as

```
showF :: (x -> b) -> ((Free f x -> b) -> f (Free f x) -> b) ->  Free f x -> b
showF backLiftValue backLiftF  = fix (showFU backLiftValue backLiftF)
    where
      showFU :: (x -> b) -> ((Free f x -> b) -> f (Free f x) -> b) -> (Free f x -> b) -> Free f x -> b
      showFU backLiftValue backLiftF next = go . runIdentity . runFreeT where
          go (FreeF c ) = backLiftF next  c
          go (Pure x) =   backLiftValue x
```

which is easy to call if we have a polymorphic function like (using `Choice x =  Choice x x` as a functor)

```
showChoice :: forall x. (x -> String) ->  Choice x -> String
showChoice show (Choice a b) =  "Choice (" ++ show  a ++  "," ++ show b ++ ")"
```

But that seems quite complicated for a simple operation...
What other approaches are there to go from `f x -> b` to `Free f x -> b`  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`iter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html) and `fmap`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad.Free

data Choice x = Choice x x deriving (Functor)

-- iter :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Free f a -> a
-- iter _   (Pure a) = a
-- iter phi (Free m) = phi (iter phi <$> m)

showFreeChoice :: Show a => Free Choice a -> String
showFreeChoice =
      iter (\(Choice l r) -> "(Choice " ++ l ++ " " ++ r ++ ")")
    . fmap (\a -> "(Pure " ++ show a ++ ")")
```

`fmap` converts from `Free f a` to `Free f b`, and `iter` does the rest. You could factor this out, and maybe get a bit better performance:

```
iter' :: Functor f => (f b -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Free f a -> b
iter' f g = go where
  go (Pure a)  = g a
  go (Free fa) = f (go <$> fa)
```

Comment: ah, that's nicer ! thank you. now I see it's obvious one had to look for translating an algebra for `f`  to an algebra for `Free f` ..

Comment: I like your `iter'`. I tried to find something serving that general purpose recently (feeling confident there must be one) but somehow failed to hit on the right type.

Comment: It might be worth benchmarking this against `iter' f g = go where ...`. Some measurements back when indicated that this tends to be good when at least two arguments stay constant through the recursion.

Comment: I should mention too that `Functor f => forall b. (f b -> b) -> (a -> b) -> b` is equivalent to `Free f a` and is the definition of the [Church free monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/Control-Monad-Free-Church.html), and [`toF`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-Free-Church.html#toF) is the same as `iter'`.

Comment: @AndrásKovács nice, thanks for spotting and adding this here. I wanted to read about Cayley representation of those things, which encompasses codensity as a special case so that might be a useful link

Comment: btw, this iter' is mentioned by Nicolas Wu who call it handle https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/6733-transformers-handlers-in-disguise